# vue 3 composition multiple input with same ref or retrieve all input containing the same text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a component named `InputWithValidation` that
I inserted in a form with some other components and I'm trying to get all instance to check if they are all valid at once.

With one `InputVithValidation` I would have check if it's valid this way:

```html
<script setup>
   import { ref } from 'vue'
   const inputEmail = ref(null);

   function submit(){
      if(inputEmail.isValid()){
         //call API
      }
   }
</script>
<template>
   <form>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputEmail" type="email" validationType="EMAIL"/>
      <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>

</template>
```

But I actually have multiple `InputWithValidation` in my form:

```html
<template>
   <form>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputEmail" type="email" validationType="EMAIL"/>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputFirstName" type="text" validationType="TEXT"/>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputEmail" type="text" validationType="TEXT"/>
      <!-- ... -->
      <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
</template>
```

And I wish to avoid this:

```html
<script setup>
   import { ref } from 'vue'

   const inputEmail = ref(null);
   const inputFirstName = ref(null);
   const inputEmail = ref(null);
   //....
</script>
```

I tried to replicate the `$refs` array of the option API or the comportment with a `ref` in a `v-for` list by setting the same `ref` to all my components and get it as `array`:

```html
<script setup>
   import { ref } from 'vue'
   const inputs = ref([]);

   function submit(){
      if(inputs.find(input => !input.isValid()) == null){
         //call API
      }
   }
</script>
<template>
   <form>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputs" type="email" validationType="EMAIL"/>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputs" type="text" validationType="TEXT"/>
      <InputWithValidation ref="inputs" type="text" validationType="TEXT"/>
      <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
</template>
```

But it's not working.

Is there anyway to retrieve all `refs`at once ?

Comment: I believe if you use "ref="inputs" for all inputs you are just assigning the ref and then overwriting it 2 times, you cannot avoid to create one ref for each input. However if you like to cycle your refs in a loop you always can put them in an Array.. But the ref needs to be unique

Comment: Yes that's what I though. But there is no way to retrieve all available refs from the current component ? I could filter by ref name like "all ref name including 'input'".

Comment: Don't think so..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assign all your "input" elements to a javascript data structure of your choice by using Vue "Function Refs".

In your template:

```
<InputWithValidation ref="myAddRefFunction" ... />
<InputWithValidation ref="myAddRefFunction" ... />
etc
```

Then in your "script setup" section:

```
const inputRefs = ref(new Set())

function myAddRefFunction(el) {
  inputRefs.value.add(el)
}

function ValidateAll() {
  const validationResults = []
  for (const inputComponent of inputRefs.value) {
     validationResults.push(await inputComponent.validate())
  }
  return validationResults
}
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try it, thanks !

Comment: Sorry for the delay, `myAddRefFunction` is never called in this way... so not working.

Comment: You want to use  :ref="myAddRefFunction", note the ':' to make it work.